# Buttons don't appear when compiling (GWT)

Tags: java, gwt

I am writing a GWT program in Eclipse but the buttons I am making don't appear. I don't know why. I have checked the whole program more than 3 times. When I compile it 2 buttons should appear "Landscape 1" & "Landscape 2". I haven't implemented anything in the clickhandlers as I want to let them appear at first :) This is my mainview:

```
package test.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;

public class MainView extends Composite{
private VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
private VerticalPanel contentPanel;

public MainView(){
    initWidget(this.vPanel);
    this.vPanel.setBorderWidth(1);

    MenuView menu = new MenuView();
    this.vPanel.add(menu);

    this.contentPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    this.vPanel.add(contentPanel);

}

}
```

This is my menuview:

```
package test.client;

import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;

public class MenuView extends Composite {
private HorizontalPanel hPanel = new HorizontalPanel();

public MenuView(){
    initWidget(this.hPanel);

    Button landscape1Btn = new Button("Landscape 1");
    landscape1Btn.addClickHandler(new LS1ClickHandler());
    this.hPanel.add(landscape1Btn);

    Button landscape2Btn = new Button("Landscape 2");
    landscape2Btn.addClickHandler(new LS2ClickHandler());
    this.hPanel.add(landscape2Btn);
}
private class LS1ClickHandler implements ClickHandler{

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
private class LS2ClickHandler implements ClickHandler{

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
}
```

This is the main class:

```
package test.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

/**
* Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
*/
public class GWT implements EntryPoint {

/**
 * This is the entry point method.
 */
public void onModuleLoad() {
    MainView mainView = new MainView();
    RootPanel.get().add(mainView);
}
}
```

Html class:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">   
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="GWT.css">
<title>My first GWT project</title>   
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="gwt/gwt.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
<noscript>
<div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
</div>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are they in the DOM but not showing or just not there? Is there any JS or HTTP error? How are you testing/deploying/launching?

Comment: No. Have fixed it :) The problem was that Eclipse didn't define the entry point the gwt.xml file